# ¿Cómo puedo importar un módulo con tilde en Python?

Tags: python

Sé que es una mala práctica pero tengo curiosidad.

Este me funciona para crear una ruta de carpeta por defecto:

```
sys.path.append(('Módulo').decode('utf-8'))
```

Pero esto:

```
import Módulo
```

No funciona. ¿Qué debería hacer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entiendo que estás hablando de python2, ya que en python 3 no hay problema alguno, como puedes ver aqui:

```py
# coding: utf-8
# Contenido del fichero Módulo.py
def funcion():
    print("Función del módulo")
if __name__ != "__main__":
    print("¡Módulo importado!")
```

Y en un intérprete:

```py
>>> import Módulo
¡Módulo importado!
>>> Módulo.funcion()
Función del módulo
```

En cambio en python2, el mismo intento es un error de sintaxis:

```py
>>> import Módulo
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import Módulo
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

El error se debe a que en Python 2 los identificadores no pueden llevar tildes (y la importación de un módulo crea un identificador con ese mismo nombre, para poder acceder al espacio de nombres de ese módulo, como hice antes con `Módulo.funcion()`).

Aún así es posible importarlo haciendo uso de la biblioteca [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) (renombrada a `import` a partir de python 3.4), que te permite interactuar a bajo nivel con las funciones que python usa para importar.

La forma más sencilla es usar `imp.find_module()` para que te encuentre el módulo en la cadena de paths, y te devuelva una tupla (tres elementos) que necesitas para pasárselo a `imp.load_module()`, que es quien verdaderamente carga el módulo. A `load_module()` también tienes que pasarle un parámetro con el nombre que recibirá "internamente" el módulo.

El valor retornado por `imp.load_module()` es el módulo en sí, que asignarás a una variable para poder acceder a su *namespace*. Lógicamente el nombre de esa variable no puede tener tildes en Python2.

Por tanto haríamos algo así:

```py
>>> import imp
>>> datos_modulo = imp.find_module("Módulo")
>>> mi_modulo = imp.load_module("Módulo", *datos_modulo)
¡Módulo importado!
>>> mi_modulo.funcion()
Función del módulo
```

El primer parámetro que pasamos al cargar el módulo (la cadena `"Módulo"`) es lo que éste recibirá en la variable `__name__`, y también podemos acceder a ese nombre vía `mi_modulo.__name__`.

Comment: Gracias! Funcionó!

Answer (score 3):

En Python 3 como ya comentó @abulafia en su respuesta no hay problema, en Python 2.7 se puede también usar `importlib.import_module`.

La biblioteca `importlib` vino a nosotros en Python 3.1 siendo la opción preferida frente a `imp`. No obstante, en Python 2.7 la versión implementada de `importlib` es mínima, pero tiene justo lo que necesitamos para este caso.

Hay que tener una cosa en cuenta cuando se usa `imp` o `importlib`: la **codificación usada por el sistema de archivos del SO**. Si intentamos hacer en Windows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import importlib
importlib.import_module("Módulo")
```

Nos podemos encontrar con un bonito error aparentemente sin sentido:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
>     modulo = importlib.import_module("Módulo")
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>     __import__(name)
> ImportError: No module named Módulo
> ```

La causa es que usa *utf-16-le* como codificación en el sistema de archivos. **Exactamente lo mismo pasa si usamos `imp`**. Nos podemos valer en este caso de `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` para codificar de forma correcta la cadena :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import importlib
import sys

nombre_mod = u"Módulo"
modulo = importlib.import_module(nombre_mod.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()))
# modulo.foo()
```

En unix-like es común usar UTF-8 también para el sistema de archivos, lo que causa que el código inicial que ocasionaba el error en Windows funcione, siempre y cuando guardemos el módulo con codificación UTF-8 y coloquemos `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` para que el intérprete trate al código fuente con esta codificación.